# How to write Regular expression for minimum one character in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have small requirement in Regular expression,here I need minimum of one letter of Alphabets and followed by numbers and special characters. I tried the following regular expressions but I'm not getting the solution.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/\s,.]+$/
```

and

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need minimum of one letter of Alphabets

```
[a-z]+
```

> and followed by numbers and special characters.

```
[0-9_\/\s,.-]+
```

Combined together you would get this:

```
/^[a-z]+[0-9_\/\s,.-]+$/i
```

The /i modifier is added for case insensitive matching of alphabetical characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
/^[a-z][\d_\s,.]+$/i
```

To clarify what this does:

```
^[a-z] // must start with a letter (only one) add '+' for "at least one"
[\d_\s,.]+$ // followed by at least one number, underscore, space, comma or dot.
/i // case-insensitive
```

Comment: it might need to be `/^[a-z]+[\d_\s,.]+$/`, `/^[a-z]+[\d_\s,.]*$/` or `/^[a-z][\d_\s,.]*$/`, depending on if the requirement is "one or more alphabetical characters" followed by either "one or more special characters" or "zero or more special characters"

Comment: Yeah it might. I'm guessing a bit here... The question wasn't very clear.

Comment: I agree, and yours is a solid answer, just wanted to provide some possible alternatives in case that didn't exactly fit what the asker was looking for.

Comment: I added some clarification in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You need the other character selection to be separate.  I'm confused as to what "numbers and special characters" means, but try:

```
/^[a-z]+[^a-z]+$/i
```